# Grails: Calling permission-protected Service method from BootStrapDevelopment

Tags: grails, spring-security, initialization

I have a Grails Domain class that has some required preprocessing before being saved in the database.  This preprocessing is done in a Grails service method.

Our Grails Service methods are all protected with required User Roles and the Spring Security Service.

I would like to prepopulate a lot of these Domain classes from BootStrapDevelopment.

However I cannot call the Service method as the BootStrapDevelopment does not have the required Role.

I have searched but cannot find how to force the BootStrapDevelopment to use a specific Role.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a specific admin user and associate the role. Then wrap your inserts in `SpringSecurityUtils.doWithAuth()`. This will consider the admin user as authenticated for everything you execute inside the closure. Example (incomplete):

```
class BootStrapDevelopment {
  def init = {
    //after creating the user...
    SpringSecurityUtils.doWithAuth("USERNAME") {
      //create and save domains...
      MyDomain myDomain = new MyDomain()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah.  I did not realize that this really was a SpringSecurity issue.  I thought that it was a Grails problem.  Thanks.